# Split the quote object to multiple quotes with respect to category

Tags: magento-1.7, php, quote, edit-order, order-duplication

I have successfully split the quote to multiple quotes and the orders are being placed seperatly for every category.
Product price and subtotals are successfully calculated according to the products items in a quote order. But shipping charges are assigned multiply.
Suppose if I order 3 items each of different category. The shipping charges will be $15 ( 5 for 1 product).
When I place the 3 orders ( as 1 1 product of each category) each category has been charged $15 instead $5 .What should I do?

Comment: If you have three orders, you have three times shipping. What do you want to achieve? Have one order with fill shipping and the others with zero or have all orders with 1/<#orders> times shipping?

Comment: I want to have shipping charges on each order with respect to products in that order. Shipping charges must also be splited not accumnulatly charged to every quote. Ie $5 to each quote not $15 to each quote (if products count is 3 and flate rate is charged.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to set the shipping method to free shipping on quotes 2+ and collect shipping only on the first quote.